# Matplotlib exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS

Tags: python, matplotlib

I could find threads with similar error but unfortunately it could not help me. Can somebody help me to better understand the error please? My apologize in advance, I could bet that there is better way to write this bulk of code.

The code:

```
years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
days = mdates.DayLocator()  # every day
years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
ax.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=5)
ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(vol.index), np.array(vol['BTC']), label='BTC')
ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(vol.index), np.array(vol['ETH']), label='ETH')
ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(vol.index), np.array(vol['XRP']), label='XRP')
ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(vol.index), np.array(vol['BCH']), label='BCH')
ax.legend(loc="upper left", fontsize='small')
fig.suptitle('(1 day volatility (7 days vol x sqrt(1/7)', fontsize=16)

# format the ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)
ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.format_ydata = lambda x: '$%1.2f' % x  # format the price.
ax.grid(True)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

imgdata = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(imgdata, format="png")
imgdata.seek(0)
```

The error:

```
  File "daily_report.py", line 542, in <module>
    fig.savefig(imgdata, format="png")
 ...
    len(locs), locs[0], locs[-1]))
RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 1607 ticks from 718360.0 to 719966.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS
```

Comment: It seems to be an error with too many scales. Can I fix it by changing `days.MAXTICKS=500`?

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks ! it worked